# Erro ao criar Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, rmi

Fui executar uma aplicação rmi no Eclipse Luna e apareceu a seguinte mensagem :

> "Could not create the `Java Virtual Machine`. `A fatal exception has
>   occurred. Program will closed.`".

O sistema operacional utilizado é o Windows 7. Como devo proceder?

Comment: A solução resolveu o problema? de uma indicação do que aconteceu de errado (caso não funcionou).

Answer (score 2):

A causa do problema é  a falta de registro de uma variável de ambiente do sistema chamada `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, alguns programas usam ela como parâmetro de inicialização.

A solução é bastante simples, basta adicionar tal variável e seu respectivo valor ao escopo de variáveis do sistema.

Variável: **_JAVA_OPTIONS**

Valor: **-Xmx1g**

Clique com o botão direito sobre o ícone “Meu Computador” na área de trabalho e depois em Propriedades.

Na aba Avançado clique em Variáveis de Ambiente.

Na janela que abrir clique em Novo e adicione o respectivo nome (**_JAVA_OPTIONS**) e valor (**-Xmx1g**) da variável.

Fonte: [Link](http://www.emidioleite.com.br/solucao-do-problema-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-ao-executar-rais-2012-ou-qualquer-outro-programa-baseado-em-java/)